# Random Lines Appearing in HTML Email on outlook 2016

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, mailchimp

We've been using mailchimp for creating simple email templates then exporting the code and using it in other clients to send those ones out. The problem im having are these random lines under certain tables and between others. I've tried adding a blank `<td>` with black background colour and specific width and heights but that doesn't seem to get rid of the white lines. Here is what the part at the bottom looks like in office 2016:[image: Office2016]

Ignore the yellow highlight text

This is what it looks like on other email clients and browsers:[image]

Apologies for the poor quality but as you can see there are white lines under the text tables and between the text and buttons. Here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"> <head><!--[if gte mso 15]> <xml> <o:OfficeDocumentSettings> <o:AllowPNG/> <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch> </o:OfficeDocumentSettings> </xml><![endif]--><!--[if gt mso 15]> <style type="text/css" media="all"> /* Outlook 2016 Height Fix */ table, tr, td{border-collapse: collapse;}tr{font-size:0px; line-height:0px; border-collapse: collapse;}</style><![endif]--> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <title>An Athena for Every Situation</title> <style type="text/css"> p{margin:10px 0; padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{display:block; margin:0; padding:0;}img,a img{border:0; height:auto; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}body,#bodyTable,#bodyCell{height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; width:100%;}.mcnPreviewText{display:none !important;}#outlook a{padding:0;}img{-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}table{mso-table-lspace:0; mso-table-rspace:0;}.ReadMsgBody{width:100%;}.ExternalClass{width:100%;}p,a,li,td,blockquote{mso-line-height-rule:exactly;}a[href^=tel],a[href^=sms]{color:inherit; cursor:default; text-decoration:none;}p,a,li,td,body,table,blockquote{-ms-text-size-adjust:100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;}.ExternalClass,.ExternalClass p,.ExternalClass td,.ExternalClass div,.ExternalClass span,.ExternalClass font{line-height:100%;}a[x-apple-data-detectors]{color:inherit !important; text-decoration:none !important; font-size:inherit !important; font-family:inherit !important; font-weight:inherit !important; line-height:inherit !important;}#bodyCell{padding:10px;}.templateContainer{max-width:600px !important;}a.mcnButton{display:block;}.mcnImage{vertical-align:bottom;}.mcnTextContent{word-break:break-word;}.mcnTextContent img{height:auto !important;}.mcnDividerBlock{table-layout:fixed !important;}body,#bodyTable{background-color:#ffffff;}#bodyCell{border-top:0;}.templateContainer{border:0;}h1{color:#202020; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:26px; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; line-height:125%; letter-spacing:normal; text-align:left;}h2{color:#202020; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:22px; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; line-height:125%; letter-spacing:normal; text-align:left;}h3{color:#202020; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:20px; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; line-height:125%; letter-spacing:normal; text-align:left;}h4{color:#202020; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:18px; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; line-height:125%; letter-spacing:normal; text-align:left;}#templatePreheader{background-color:#ffffff; background-image:none; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center; background-size:cover; border-top:0; border-bottom:0; padding-top:9px; padding-bottom:9px;}#templatePreheader .mcnTextContent,#templatePreheader .mcnTextContent p{color:#656565; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:12px; line-height:150%; text-align:left;}#templatePreheader .mcnTextContent a,#templatePreheader .mcnTextContent p a{color:#656565; font-weight:normal; text-decoration:underline;}#templateHeader{background-color:#ffffff; background-image:none; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center; background-size:cover; border-top:0; border-bottom:0; padding-bottom:0;}#templateHeader .mcnTextContent,#templateHeader .mcnTextContent p{color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:16px; line-height:150%; text-align:left;}#templateHeader .mcnTextContent a,#templateHeader .mcnTextContent p a{color:#2BAADF; font-weight:normal; text-decoration:underline;}#templateBody{background-color:#000000; background-image:none; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center; background-size:cover; border-top:0; border-bottom:0; padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0;}#templateBody .mcnTextContent,#templateBody .mcnTextContent p{color:#202020; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:16px; line-height:150%; text-align:left;}#templateBody .mcnTextContent a,#templateBody .mcnTextContent p a{color:#2BAADF; font-weight:normal; text-decoration:underline;}#templateColumns{background-color:#000000; background-image:none; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center; background-size:cover; border-top:0; border-bottom:2px solid #EAEAEA; padding-top:0; padding-bottom:9px;}#templateColumns .columnContainer .mcnTextContent,#templateColumns .columnContainer .mcnTextContent p{color:#FFF; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:12px; line-height:150%; text-align:left;}#templateColumns .columnContainer .mcnTextContent a,#templateColumns .columnContainer .mcnTextContent p a{color:#2BAADF; font-weight:normal; text-decoration:underline;}#templateFooter{background-color:#000000; background-image:none; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center; background-size:cover; border-top:0; border-bottom:0; padding-top:9px; padding-bottom:9px;}#templateFooter .mcnTextContent,#templateFooter .mcnTextContent p{color:#656565; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:12px; line-height:150%; text-align:center;}#templateFooterSage .mcnTextContent a,#templateFooter .mcnTextContent p a{color:#656565; font-weight:normal; text-decoration:underline;}#templateFooterSage .mcnTextContent,#templateFooter .mcnTextContent p{color:#656565; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:12px; line-height:150%; text-align:center;}#templateFooter .mcnTextContent a,#templateFooter .mcnTextContent p a{color:#656565; font-weight:normal; text-decoration:underline;}</style></head> <body> <span class="mcnPreviewText" style="display:none; font-size:0px; line-height:0px; max-height:0px; max-width:0px; opacity:0; overflow:hidden; visibility:hidden; mso-hide:all;">An Athena for Every Situation</span> <center> <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable"> <tr> <td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell"><!--[if gte mso 9]> <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="width:600px;"> <tr> <td align="center" valign="top" width="600" style="width:600px;"><![endif]--> <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateContainer"> <tr> <td valign="top" id="templatePreheader"><table class="mcnTextBlock" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter"> <tr> <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top:9px;" valign="top"><!--[if mso]> <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100%;"> <tr><![endif]--><!--[if mso]> <td valign="top" width="210" style="width:210px;"><![endif]--> <table style="max-width:210px;" class="mcnTextContentContainer" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left" > <tbody><tr> <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-top:0; padding-left:18px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-right:18px;" valign="top"> </td></tr></tbody></table><!--[if mso]> </td><![endif]--><!--[if mso]> <td valign="top" width="390" style="width:390px;"><![endif]--> <table style="max-width:390px;" class="mcnTextContentContainer" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left"> <tbody><tr> <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-top:0; padding-left:18px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-right:18px;" valign="top"> <a href="" target="_blank">View this email in your browser</a> </td></tr></tbody></table><!--[if mso]> </td><![endif]--><!--[if mso]> </tr></table><![endif]--> </td></tr></tbody> </table></td></tr><tr> <td valign="top" id="templateHeader"><table class="mcnImageBlock" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter"> <tr> <td style="padding:0px" class="mcnImageBlockInner" valign="top"> <table class="mcnImageContentContainer" style="min-width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left"> <tbody><tr> <td class="mcnImageContent" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; text-align:center;" valign="top"> <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/ea957616d7790e5fcf5872a25/images/2dc82f25-c77f-4372-a010-f0788c2f0d37.jpg" style="max-width:900px; padding-bottom: 0; display: inline !important; vertical-align: bottom;" class="mcnImage" width="600" align="middle"> </td></tr></tbody></table> </td></tr></tbody> </table></td></tr><tr> <td valign="top" id="templateBody"><table class="mcnBoxedTextBlock" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><!--[if gte mso 9]> <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><![endif]--> <tbody class="mcnBoxedTextBlockOuter"> <tr> <td class="mcnBoxedTextBlockInner" valign="top"><!--[if gte mso 9]> <td align="center" valign="top" "><![endif]--> <table style="min-width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;" class="mcnBoxedTextContentContainer" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left"> <tbody><tr> <td style="padding-top:9px; padding-left:18px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-right:18px;"> <table class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="min-width: 100% !important;background-color: #000000;border: 20px none;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="18" border="0"> <tbody><tr> <td class="mcnTextContent" style="color: #F2F2F2;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;" valign="top"> <span style="font-size:27px"><span style="color: #FFFFFF;"><span style="font-family:merriweather sans,helvetica neue,helvetica,arial,sans-serif">An Athena for <strong>EVERY</strong> situation</span></span></span> </td></tr></tbody></table> </td></tr></tbody></table><!--[if gte mso 9]> </td><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]> </tr></table><![endif]--> </td></tr></tbody> </table><table class="mcnTextBlock" style="min-width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter"> <tr> <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top:9px;" valign="top"><!--[if mso]> <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100%;"> <tr><![endif]--><!--[if mso]> <td valign="top" width="600" style="width:600px;"><![endif]--> <table style="max-width:100%; min-width:100%;" class="mcnTextContentContainer" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left"> <tbody><tr> <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-top:0; padding-right:18px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-left:18px;" valign="top"> <div style="text-align: center;"><span style="color:#FFFFFF">NEW RELEASES OUT NOW</span></div></td></tr></tbody></table><!--[if mso]> </td><![endif]--><!--[if mso]> </tr></table><![endif]--> </td></tr></tbody> </table><table class="mcnImageBlock" style="min-width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter"> <tr> <td style="padding:9px" class="mcnImageBlockInner" valign="top"> <table class="mcnImageContentContainer" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left"> <tbody><tr> <td class="mcnImageContent" style="padding-right: 9px; padding-left: 9px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; text-align:center;" valign="top"> <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/ea957616d7790e5fcf5872a25/images/c0528a15-f340-4211-bb27-530086ff99ca.png" style="max-width:1087px; padding-bottom: 0; display: inline !important; vertical-align: bottom;" class="mcnImage" width="564" align="middle"> </td></tr></tbody></table> </td></tr></tbody> </table></td></tr><tr> <td valign="top" id="templateColumns"><!--[if gte mso 9]> <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="width:600px;"> <tr> <td align="center" valign="top" width="200" height="95" style="width:200px; height:95px;"><![endif]--> <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" height="95" class="columnWrapper"> <tr> <td valign="top" class="columnContainer"><table class="mcnCaptionBlock" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter"> <tr> <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" style="padding:9px;" valign="top"> <table class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="false" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left"> <tbody><tr> <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" style="padding:0 9px 9px 9px;" valign="top" align="center"> <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/ea957616d7790e5fcf5872a25/images/1810cbf7-1d5c-4fbb-901c-ba3394c2bad0.jpg" style="max-width:106px;" class="mcnImage" width="106"> </td></tr><tr> <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding:0 9px 0 9px; height:95px;" width="164" height="95" valign="top"> <span style="font-family:helvetica neue,helvetica,arial,verdana,sans-serif"><span style="color:#cc0033"><strong>Athena™ 850</strong></span><br><span style="color:#FFFFFF"><span style="font-size:12px">- Travels while raised<br>- Transportable by trailer<br>- Non marking tracks as standard</span></span></span><br></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table> </td></tr></tbody> </table></td></tr></table><!--[if gte mso 9]> </td><td align="center" valign="top" width="200" style="width:200px;"><![endif]--> <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" class="columnWrapper"> <tr> <td valign="top" class="columnContainer"><table class="mcnCaptionBlock" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter"> <tr> <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" style="padding:9px;" valign="top"> <table class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="false" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left"> <tbody><tr> <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" style="padding:0 9px 9px 9px;" valign="top" align="center"> <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/ea957616d7790e5fcf5872a25/images/1810cbf7-1d5c-4fbb-901c-ba3394c2bad0.jpg" style="max-width:106px;" class="mcnImage" width="106"> </td></tr><tr> <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding:0 9px 0 9px;" width="164" valign="top"> <span style="font-family:helvetica neue,helvetica,arial,verdana,sans-serif"><span style="color:#cc0033"><strong>Athena™ HE-&nbsp; New release</strong></span><br><span style="color:#FFFFFF"><span style="font-size:12px">- Fits through a door<br>- Indoor and outdoor use<br>- Self-levels on up to 20 degrees<br>- Transportable by trailer</span></span></span><br>&nbsp; </td></tr></tbody></table> </td></tr></tbody> </table></td></tr></table><!--[if gte mso 9]> </td><td align="center" valign="top" width="200" style="width:200px;"><![endif]--> <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" class="columnWrapper"> <tr> <td valign="top" class="columnContainer"><table class="mcnCaptionBlock" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter"> <tr> <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" style="padding:9px;" valign="top"> <table class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="false" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left"> <tbody><tr> <td class="mcnCaptionBottomImageContent" style="padding:0 9px 9px 9px;" valign="top" align="center"> <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/ea957616d7790e5fcf5872a25/images/1810cbf7-1d5c-4fbb-901c-ba3394c2bad0.jpg" style="max-width:106px;" class="mcnImage" width="106"> </td></tr><tr> <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding:0 9px 0 9px;" width="164" valign="top"> <span style="font-family:helvetica neue,helvetica,arial,verdana,sans-serif"><span style="color:#cc0033"><strong>Athena™ EVO 10.90 - New release</strong></span><br><span style="color:#FFFFFF"><span style="font-size:12px">- New 10 metre working height<br>- Dynamic and Proactive Levelling capabilities<br>- Drives and self levels while in the air<br>- New larger basket design</span></span></span> </td></tr></tbody></table> </td></tr></tbody> </table></td></tr></table><!--[if gte mso 9]> </td></tr></table><![endif]--> </td></tr><tr> <td valign="top" id="templateFooter"><table class="mcnBoxedTextBlock" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><!--[if gte mso 9]> <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><![endif]--> <tbody class="mcnBoxedTextBlockOuter"> <tr> <td class="mcnBoxedTextBlockInner" valign="top"><!--[if gte mso 9]> <td align="center" valign="top" "><![endif]--> <table style="min-width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;" class="mcnBoxedTextContentContainer" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left"> <tbody><tr> <td style="padding-top:9px; padding-left:18px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-right:18px;"> <table class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="min-width: 100% !important;background-color: #000000;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="18" border="0"> <tbody><tr> <td class="mcnTextContent" style="color: #F2F2F2;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;text-align: center;" valign="top"> <span style="font-size:16px"><strong><span style="color: #CC0033;"><span style="font-family:helvetica neue,helvetica,arial,verdana,sans-serif">CLICK THROUGH TO DOWNLOAD A SPEC SHEET OR TO WATCH THE ATHENA™ IN ACTION</span></span></strong></span> </td></tr></tbody></table> </td></tr></tbody></table><!--[if gte mso 9]> </td><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]> </tr></table><![endif]--> </td></tr></tbody> </table><table class="mcnCaptionBlock" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter"> <tr> <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" style="padding:9px;" valign="top"> <table class="mcnCaptionLeftContentOuter" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody><tr> <td class="mcnCaptionLeftContentInner" style="padding:0 9px ;" valign="top"> <table class="mcnCaptionLeftImageContentContainer" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="right"> <tbody><tr> <td class="mcnCaptionLeftImageContent" valign="top"> <a href="http://v3au.zone-secure.net/drive/9982/339883/" title="" class="" target="_blank"> <img alt="" src="athena.jpg" style="max-width:709px;" class="mcnImage" width="264"> </a> </td></tr></tbody></table> <table class="mcnCaptionLeftTextContentContainer" width="264" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left"> <tbody><tr> <td class="mcnTextContent" valign="top"> <div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:14px"><span style="font-family:helvetica neue,helvetica,arial,verdana,sans-serif"><span style="color: #FFFFFF;">For a full range of ASPAC Specialist Access equipment</span></span></span></div></td></tr></tbody></table> </td></tr></tbody></table> </td></tr></tbody> </table><table class="mcnDividerBlock" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody class="mcnDividerBlockOuter"> <tr> <td class="mcnDividerBlockInner" style="min-width:100%; padding:18px;"> <table class="mcnDividerContent" style="min-width: 100%;border-top: 2px solid #FFFFFF;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody><tr> <td> <span></span> </td></tr></tbody></table> </td></tr></tbody> </table><table class="mcnCaptionBlock" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter"> <tr> <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" style="padding:9px;" valign="top"> <table class="mcnCaptionLeftContentOuter" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody><tr> <td class="mcnCaptionLeftContentInner" style="padding:0 9px ;" valign="top"> <table class="mcnCaptionLeftImageContentContainer" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="right"> <tbody><tr> <td class="mcnCaptionLeftImageContent" valign="top"> <a href="http://www.aspacgroup.com.au" title="" class="" target="_blank"> <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/ea957616d7790e5fcf5872a25/images/d733278d-2c92-4a9f-9be1-4f0c6b5266a8.jpg" style="max-width:709px;" class="mcnImage" width="264"> </a> </td></tr></tbody></table> <table class="mcnCaptionLeftTextContentContainer" width="264" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left"> <tbody><tr> <td class="mcnTextContent" valign="top"> <div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:14px"><span style="font-family:helvetica neue,helvetica,arial,verdana,sans-serif"><span style="color: #FFFFFF;">For a full range of ASPAC Specialist Access equipment</span></span></span></div></td></tr></tbody></table> </td></tr></tbody></table> </td></tr></tbody> </table><table class="mcnBoxedTextBlock" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><!--[if gte mso 9]> <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><![endif]--> <tbody class="mcnBoxedTextBlockOuter"> <tr> <td class="mcnBoxedTextBlockInner" valign="top"><!--[if gte mso 9]> <td align="center" valign="top" "><![endif]--> <table style="min-width:100%;" class="mcnBoxedTextContentContainer" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left"> <tbody><tr> <td style="padding-top:9px; padding-left:18px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-right:18px;"> <table class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="min-width: 100% !important;background-color: #DA2127;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="18" border="0"> <tbody><tr> <td class="mcnTextContent" style="color: #F2F2F2;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;text-align: center;" valign="top"> <div style="text-align: center;"><span style="color:#FFFFFF"><span style="font-family:helvetica neue,helvetica,arial,verdana,sans-serif"><strong>After Sales Service: </strong></span></span></div><span style="color:#FFFFFF"><span style="font-family:helvetica neue,helvetica,arial,verdana,sans-serif">Maintenance agreements available 24 hour phone support</span></span> </td></tr></tbody></table> </td></tr></tbody></table><!--[if gte mso 9]> </td><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]> </tr></table><![endif]--> </td></tr></tbody> </table></td></tr><tr> <td valign="top" id="templateFooterSage"> <table class="mcnDividerBlock" style="min-width:100%;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody class="mcnDividerBlockOuter"> <tr> <td class="mcnDividerBlockInner" style="min-width:100%;padding:18px;"> <table class="mcnDividerContent" style="min-width:100%;border-top:2px solid #EAEAEA;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody> <tr> <td> <span></span> </td></tr></tbody> </table> </td></tr></tbody> </table> <table class="mcnCaptionBlock" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter"> <tr> <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" style="padding:9px;" valign="top"> <table class="mcnCaptionRightContentOuter" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody> <tr> <td class="mcnCaptionRightContentInner" style="padding:0 9px;" valign="top"> <table class="mcnCaptionRightImageContentContainer" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left"> <tbody> <tr> <td class="mcnCaptionRightImageContent" valign="top"> <img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/ea957616d7790e5fcf5872a25/images/0d9da147-38d0-4b35-b132-9798550e40f9.jpg" style="max-width:60px;" class="mcnImage" width="60"> </td></tr></tbody> </table> <table class="mcnCaptionRightTextContentContainer" width="396" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="right"> <tbody> <tr> <td class="mcnTextContent" valign="top"> <br>info@sagemedia.com.au +61 8 6336 6430 www.sagemedia.com.au <tr> <td style="width:100px; height:20px;"></td></tr><tr class="unsub"> <td valign="top" align="center"><a href="https://www.buildaustralia.com.au/unsubscribe" style="padding: 0px 0px;font-size: 12px; text-decoration:none; font-family: font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height:14px; text-align: right;color: #888888;">click here to unsubscribe</a></td></tr></tr></td></tr></tbody> </table> </td></tr></tbody> </table> </td></tr></tbody> </table> </td></tr></table><!--[if gte mso 9]> </td></tr></table><![endif]--> </td></tr></table> </center> </body> </html>
```

Here is a JSFiddle with formatted html: https://jsfiddle.net/025ox8tp/1/

Thanks for the help. PS I had to minify the code in order to fit everything in.

Comment: I'm sure you can make the source smaller and still have something that demonstrates the problem. Anyway, the MSO specific code in your source causes the result to be bad HTML - there are now missing <table> start tags etc. Also, don't use an XHTML doctype. Email doesn't do XHTML.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah as I said its a template straight from mail chimp. I'll change the doctype and try and add some `<table>` tags to some of the MSO code. Although I'll have to do it by trail and error

Comment: Ive changed the doctype to html5 and now my anti-spam application doesnt  like it and wants it back to XHTML. Anyway changing it changed little. Next I'll look for the missing `<table>' tags i believe they are in the MSO part of the code

Comment: @MrLister I cant seem to find where to place the missing `<table>` tags. Is it somewhere within one of the MSO coded parts or just in the html in general

Comment: The HTML has quote a lot of td's declared and outlook conditional statement creating another set of td's with it (line 420 - 447). You might want to look into that. Can you also check if your template is zoomed out of zoomed in by chance? I had seen this happening on iOS (long shot i know)

Comment: @Syfer Thanks i'll look into that. Its not zoomed in I dont think. The problem is only visible on outlook and not on any other email clients.

Comment: Maybe then try removing the extra code, it might help.

Comment: @Syfer The extra code as in the office commented code? I've tried and the formatting is even worse in outlook. Ive been rebuilding the template from scratch to see if I can find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!!! It turns out it was just one computer that had an issue with this email. Other computers using outlook didnt seem to have the problem and after re-installing outlook on his computer. Problem solved

Comment: A recent Outlook update patched this issue, it's been plaguing email devs since 2016 released! Glad you managed to get round it.

Comment: it might be too late to ask which version you had right?

Comment: Well in my case it seemed to be specific to one PC with outlook2016. Not sure why that Computer with Windows 10 had the problem while all the other computers which also had outlook 2016 didnt. In any case after a re-install of outlook 2016 the Email looks fine

Answer (score 0):

This is only a workaround that works if it fits your template layout but I thought it would worth sharing.

I find out that the lines appearing are the same color as the background. Therefore setting the background color on the body would hide those imperfections ...

```html
<style>
  body { background: #000000; }
</style>
```